# Saving sklearn model to h5py

Tags: json, scikit-learn, hdf5, h5py, gridsearchcv

When I'm doing [gridsearch](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html) in sklearn it would be convinient to save different data in the same hdf5 file using h5py. Having to keep track of different files creates a mess of files that is hard to keep track on.

Of particular interest is:

- best parameters (best_params_dict)
- results of gridsearch (cv_results_dict of numpy (masked) ndarrays)
- model (best_estimator_estimator)

Since the first two are dictionaries they can be converted to strings using json.dumps and then saved into h5py as strings. However the model is a class object [so it needs to be saved with pickle](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/model_persistence.html).

h5py doesn't seem to support pickle so I'm wondering if there's any way to get around this and be able to save the model into the hdf5 file...?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to use the numpy void dtype (https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.scalars.html#numpy.void) to hold arbitrary binary data, which h5py will store as the HDF5 OPAQUE type (and labelling with other dtypes is covered at https://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/special.html#storing-other-types-as-opaque-data, but see the warning).

---

It's unclear though *why* you're using HDF5 if you're planning on dumping arbitrary data into it. If you're going to dump things as JSON and pickles, why not use zip files for example, and take advantage of the compression of the JSON?

For example, naively I'd expect `best_params_dict` to be composed of simple key-value pairs, which could be directly saved in HDF5 as attributes on a group or dataset (e.g. `dset.attrs.update(best_params_dict)`), which avoids all the issues with JSON and numbers. It's likely the other things you're interested in could be encoded in a less roundabout way, and would allow for other code to meaningfully read your data (the pickled data especially, but JSON also is generally a bad format for non-string data).